# How to deal with Yeoman's package.json conflict error?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator, yeoman-generator-angular

I am getting a package.json conflict error every time I run Yeoman scaffolding tool.Finally if I press enter the yo tool is overriding package.json and the angular application works fine but I wonder if I can stop this error from appearing every time.
Am I doing something wrong?
Here is the complete log of the yo tool when I run it :

```
Out of the box I include Bootstrap and some AngularJS recommended modules.

? Would you like to use Sass (with Compass)? No
? Would you like to include Bootstrap? Yes
? Which modules would you like to include? angular-animate.js, angular-cookies.js, angular-resource.js, angular-route.js, angular-sanitize.js, angular-touch.js
   create app/styles/main.css
   create app/index.html
   create bower.json
   create .bowerrc
   create package.json
   create Gruntfile.js
   create README.md
   invoke   angular:common:/Users/Administrator/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.2/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/app/index.js
   create     .editorconfig
   create     .gitattributes
   create     .jshintrc
   create     .yo-rc.json
   create     .gitignore
   create     test/.jshintrc
   create     app/.buildignore
   create     app/.htaccess
   create     app/404.html
   create     app/favicon.ico
   create     app/robots.txt
   create     app/views/main.html
   create     app/images/yeoman.png
   invoke   angular:main:/Users/Administrator/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.2/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/app/index.js
   create     app/scripts/app.js
   invoke   angular:controller:/Users/Administrator/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.2/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/app/index.js
   create     app/scripts/controllers/main.js
   create     test/spec/controllers/main.js
   invoke   karma:app


I'm all done. Running bower install & npm install for you to install the required dependencies. If this fails, try running the command yourself.


   invoke       angular:route
   invoke           angular:controller:/Users/Administrator/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.2/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/route/index.js
   create             app/scripts/controllers/about.js
   create             test/spec/controllers/about.js
   invoke           angular:view:/Users/Administrator/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.2/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/route/index.js
   create             app/views/about.html
   create     test/karma.conf.js
 conflict     package.json
bower bootstrap#^3.2.0          cached git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#3.3.4
bower bootstrap#^3.2.0        validate 3.3.4 against git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#^3.2.0
bower angular#^1.3.0            cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.3.15
bower angular#^1.3.0          validate 1.3.15 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#^1.3.0
bower angular-animate#^1.3.0    cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-animate.git#1.3.15
bower angular-animate#^1.3.0  validate 1.3.15 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-animate.git#^1.3.0
bower angular-resource#^1.3.0   cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-resource.git#1.3.15
bower angular-resource#^1.3.0 validate 1.3.15 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-resource.git#^1.3.0
bower angular-sanitize#^1.3.0   cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-sanitize.git#1.3.15
bower angular-sanitize#^1.3.0 validate 1.3.15 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-sanitize.git#^1.3.0
bower angular-cookies#^1.3.0    cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-cookies.git#1.3.15
bower angular-cookies#^1.3.0  validate 1.3.15 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-cookies.git#^1.3.0
bower angular-route#^1.3.0      cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-route.git#1.3.15
bower angular-route#^1.3.0    validate 1.3.15 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-route.git#^1.3.0
bower angular-touch#^1.3.0      cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-touch.git#1.3.15
bower angular-touch#^1.3.0    validate 1.3.15 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-touch.git#^1.3.0
bower angular-mocks#^1.3.0      cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-mocks.git#1.3.15
bower angular-mocks#^1.3.0    validate 1.3.15 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-mocks.git#^1.3.0
bower jquery#>= 1.9.1           cached git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#2.1.4
bower jquery#>= 1.9.1         validate 2.1.4 against git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git#>= 1.9.1
bower angular-animate#^1.3.0   install angular-animate#1.3.15
bower angular#^1.3.0           install angular#1.3.15
bower angular-cookies#^1.3.0   install angular-cookies#1.3.15
bower angular-resource#^1.3.0  install angular-resource#1.3.15
bower angular-sanitize#^1.3.0  install angular-sanitize#1.3.15
bower angular-route#^1.3.0     install angular-route#1.3.15
bower bootstrap#^3.2.0         install bootstrap#3.3.4
bower angular-mocks#^1.3.0     install angular-mocks#1.3.15
bower angular-touch#^1.3.0     install angular-touch#1.3.15
bower jquery#>= 1.9.1          install jquery#2.1.4
\
angular-animate#1.3.15 bower_components/angular-animate
└── angular#1.3.15

angular#1.3.15 bower_components/angular

angular-cookies#1.3.15 bower_components/angular-cookies
└── angular#1.3.15

angular-resource#1.3.15 bower_components/angular-resource
└── angular#1.3.15

angular-sanitize#1.3.15 bower_components/angular-sanitize
└── angular#1.3.15

angular-route#1.3.15 bower_components/angular-route
└── angular#1.3.15

bootstrap#3.3.4 bower_components/bootstrap
└── jquery#2.1.4

angular-mocks#1.3.15 bower_components/angular-mocks
└── angular#1.3.15

angular-touch#1.3.15 bower_components/angular-touch
└── angular#1.3.15

jquery#2.1.4 bower_components/jquery

> spawn-sync@1.0.6 postinstall /Users/Administrator/Work/UnravelNg/node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/node_modules/imagemin/node_modules/imagemin-gifsicle/node_modules/gifsicle/node_modules/bin-wrapper/node_modules/bin-check/node_modules/spawn-sync
> node postinstall


> spawn-sync@1.0.6 postinstall /Users/Administrator/Work/UnravelNg/node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/node_modules/imagemin/node_modules/imagemin-pngquant/node_modules/pngquant-bin/node_modules/bin-wrapper/node_modules/bin-check/node_modules/spawn-sync
> node postinstall


> spawn-sync@1.0.6 postinstall /Users/Administrator/Work/UnravelNg/node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/node_modules/imagemin/node_modules/imagemin-optipng/node_modules/optipng-bin/node_modules/bin-wrapper/node_modules/bin-check/node_modules/spawn-sync
> node postinstall


> spawn-sync@1.0.6 postinstall /Users/Administrator/Work/UnravelNg/node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/node_modules/imagemin/node_modules/imagemin-jpegtran/node_modules/jpegtran-bin/node_modules/bin-wrapper/node_modules/bin-check/node_modules/spawn-sync
> node postinstall


> jpegtran-bin@2.0.2 postinstall /Users/Administrator/Work/UnravelNg/node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/node_modules/imagemin/node_modules/imagemin-jpegtran/node_modules/jpegtran-bin
> node lib/install.js

  ✔ jpegtran pre-build test passed successfully

> optipng-bin@2.0.4 postinstall /Users/Administrator/Work/UnravelNg/node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/node_modules/imagemin/node_modules/imagemin-optipng/node_modules/optipng-bin
> node lib/install.js

  ✔ optipng pre-build test passed successfully

> pngquant-bin@3.0.0 postinstall /Users/Administrator/Work/UnravelNg/node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/node_modules/imagemin/node_modules/imagemin-pngquant/node_modules/pngquant-bin
> node lib/install.js

  ✔ pngquant pre-build test passed successfully

> gifsicle@2.0.1 postinstall /Users/Administrator/Work/UnravelNg/node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/node_modules/imagemin/node_modules/imagemin-gifsicle/node_modules/gifsicle
> node lib/install.js

  ✔ gifsicle pre-build test passed successfully

grunt-contrib-clean@0.6.0 node_modules/grunt-contrib-clean
└── rimraf@2.2.8

grunt-concurrent@1.0.0 node_modules/grunt-concurrent
├── pad-stdio@1.0.0 (lpad@1.0.0)
└── async@0.9.0

grunt-contrib-copy@0.7.0 node_modules/grunt-contrib-copy
└── chalk@0.5.1 (ansi-styles@1.1.0, escape-string-regexp@1.0.3, supports-color@0.2.0, strip-ansi@0.3.0, has-ansi@0.1.0)

jshint-stylish@1.0.2 node_modules/jshint-stylish
├── log-symbols@1.0.2
├── text-table@0.2.0
├── string-length@1.0.0 (strip-ansi@2.0.1)
└── chalk@1.0.0 (escape-string-regexp@1.0.3, ansi-styles@2.0.1, supports-color@1.3.1, strip-ansi@2.0.1, has-ansi@1.0.3)

grunt-filerev@2.3.1 node_modules/grunt-filerev
├── each-async@0.1.3
├── convert-source-map@1.1.0
└── chalk@1.0.0 (escape-string-regexp@1.0.3, ansi-styles@2.0.1, supports-color@1.3.1, strip-ansi@2.0.1, has-ansi@1.0.3)

time-grunt@1.2.0 node_modules/time-grunt
├── date-time@1.0.0
├── figures@1.3.5
├── text-table@0.2.0
├── hooker@0.2.3
├── pretty-ms@1.1.0 (parse-ms@1.0.0, get-stdin@4.0.1)
└── chalk@1.0.0 (escape-string-regexp@1.0.3, ansi-styles@2.0.1, supports-color@1.3.1, strip-ansi@2.0.1, has-ansi@1.0.3)

grunt-newer@1.1.0 node_modules/grunt-newer
├── rimraf@2.2.8
└── async@0.9.0

grunt-contrib-concat@0.5.1 node_modules/grunt-contrib-concat
├── chalk@0.5.1 (ansi-styles@1.1.0, escape-string-regexp@1.0.3, supports-color@0.2.0, strip-ansi@0.3.0, has-ansi@0.1.0)
└── source-map@0.3.0 (amdefine@0.1.0)

load-grunt-tasks@3.1.0 node_modules/load-grunt-tasks
├── multimatch@2.0.0 (array-differ@1.0.0, array-union@1.0.1, minimatch@2.0.7)
└── findup-sync@0.2.1 (glob@4.3.5)

grunt-contrib-watch@0.6.1 node_modules/grunt-contrib-watch
├── async@0.2.10
├── tiny-lr-fork@0.0.5 (debug@0.7.4, faye-websocket@0.4.4, noptify@0.0.3, qs@0.5.6)
├── gaze@0.5.1 (globule@0.1.0)
└── lodash@2.4.2

grunt-usemin@3.0.0 node_modules/grunt-usemin
├── chalk@0.5.1 (ansi-styles@1.1.0, escape-string-regexp@1.0.3, supports-color@0.2.0, has-ansi@0.1.0, strip-ansi@0.3.0)
├── debug@2.1.3 (ms@0.7.0)
└── lodash@2.4.2

grunt-contrib-connect@0.9.0 node_modules/grunt-contrib-connect
├── opn@1.0.2
├── connect-livereload@0.5.3
├── async@0.9.0
├── portscanner@1.0.0 (async@0.1.15)
└── connect@2.29.1 (utils-merge@1.0.0, cookie-signature@1.0.6, cookie@0.1.2, fresh@0.2.4, pause@0.0.1, response-time@2.3.0, vhost@3.0.0, content-type@1.0.1, basic-auth-connect@1.0.0, on-headers@1.0.0, bytes@1.0.0, parseurl@1.3.0, cookie-parser@1.3.4, depd@1.0.1, http-errors@1.3.1, qs@2.4.1, method-override@2.3.2, debug@2.1.3, connect-timeout@1.6.2, finalhandler@0.3.4, express-session@1.10.4, serve-favicon@2.2.0, csurf@1.7.0, morgan@1.5.3, type-is@1.6.2, serve-static@1.9.2, multiparty@3.3.2, errorhandler@1.3.5, compression@1.4.4, body-parser@1.12.4, serve-index@1.6.3)

grunt-contrib-htmlmin@0.4.0 node_modules/grunt-contrib-htmlmin
├── chalk@0.5.1 (ansi-styles@1.1.0, escape-string-regexp@1.0.3, supports-color@0.2.0, strip-ansi@0.3.0, has-ansi@0.1.0)
├── pretty-bytes@1.0.4 (get-stdin@4.0.1, meow@3.1.0)
└── html-minifier@0.7.2 (relateurl@0.2.6, change-case@2.3.0, concat-stream@1.4.8, cli@0.6.6, clean-css@3.1.9, uglify-js@2.4.21)

grunt-contrib-cssmin@0.12.3 node_modules/grunt-contrib-cssmin
├── chalk@1.0.0 (escape-string-regexp@1.0.3, ansi-styles@2.0.1, supports-color@1.3.1, strip-ansi@2.0.1, has-ansi@1.0.3)
├── clean-css@3.2.9 (commander@2.8.1, source-map@0.4.2)
└── maxmin@1.1.0 (figures@1.3.5, pretty-bytes@1.0.4, gzip-size@1.0.0)

grunt-contrib-uglify@0.7.0 node_modules/grunt-contrib-uglify
├── uri-path@0.0.2
├── chalk@0.5.1 (ansi-styles@1.1.0, escape-string-regexp@1.0.3, supports-color@0.2.0, has-ansi@0.1.0, strip-ansi@0.3.0)
├── lodash@2.4.2
├── uglify-js@2.4.21 (uglify-to-browserify@1.0.2, async@0.2.10, yargs@3.5.4, source-map@0.1.34)
└── maxmin@1.1.0 (figures@1.3.5, chalk@1.0.0, pretty-bytes@1.0.4, gzip-size@1.0.0)

grunt@0.4.5 node_modules/grunt
├── dateformat@1.0.2-1.2.3
├── which@1.0.9
├── eventemitter2@0.4.14
├── getobject@0.1.0
├── rimraf@2.2.8
├── colors@0.6.2
├── async@0.1.22
├── grunt-legacy-util@0.2.0
├── hooker@0.2.3
├── exit@0.1.2
├── nopt@1.0.10 (abbrev@1.0.5)
├── minimatch@0.2.14 (sigmund@1.0.0, lru-cache@2.6.2)
├── glob@3.1.21 (inherits@1.0.0, graceful-fs@1.2.3)
├── lodash@0.9.2
├── coffee-script@1.3.3
├── underscore.string@2.2.1
├── iconv-lite@0.2.11
├── findup-sync@0.1.3 (glob@3.2.11, lodash@2.4.2)
├── grunt-legacy-log@0.1.1 (underscore.string@2.3.3, lodash@2.4.2)
└── js-yaml@2.0.5 (argparse@0.1.16, esprima@1.0.4)

grunt-wiredep@2.0.0 node_modules/grunt-wiredep
└── wiredep@2.2.2 (propprop@0.3.0, minimist@1.1.1, chalk@0.5.1, through2@0.6.5, glob@4.5.3, lodash@2.4.2, bower-config@0.5.2)

grunt-ng-annotate@0.9.2 node_modules/grunt-ng-annotate
├── lodash@2.4.2
└── ng-annotate@0.15.4 (tryor@0.1.2, alter@0.2.0, simple-fmt@0.1.0, simple-is@0.2.0, stringset@0.2.1, stringmap@0.2.2, stable@0.1.5, convert-source-map@0.4.1, ordered-ast-traverse@1.1.1, optimist@0.6.1, source-map@0.1.43, acorn@0.11.0)

grunt-svgmin@2.0.1 node_modules/grunt-svgmin
├── log-symbols@1.0.2
├── each-async@1.1.1 (set-immediate-shim@1.0.1, onetime@1.0.0)
├── chalk@1.0.0 (escape-string-regexp@1.0.3, ansi-styles@2.0.1, supports-color@1.3.1, strip-ansi@2.0.1, has-ansi@1.0.3)
├── pretty-bytes@1.0.4 (get-stdin@4.0.1, meow@3.1.0)
└── svgo@0.5.1 (whet.extend@0.9.9, colors@1.0.3, mkdirp@0.5.0, coa@1.0.1, sax@0.6.1, js-yaml@3.2.7)

grunt-contrib-jshint@0.11.2 node_modules/grunt-contrib-jshint
├── hooker@0.2.3
└── jshint@2.7.0 (strip-json-comments@1.0.2, exit@0.1.2, console-browserify@1.1.0, shelljs@0.3.0, minimatch@2.0.7, cli@0.6.6, htmlparser2@3.8.2, lodash@3.6.0)

grunt-autoprefixer@2.2.0 node_modules/grunt-autoprefixer
├── diff@1.2.2
├── chalk@0.5.1 (ansi-styles@1.1.0, escape-string-regexp@1.0.3, supports-color@0.2.0, strip-ansi@0.3.0, has-ansi@0.1.0)
└── autoprefixer-core@5.1.11 (num2fraction@1.1.0, browserslist@0.2.0, postcss@4.0.6, caniuse-db@1.0.30000161)

grunt-google-cdn@0.4.3 node_modules/grunt-google-cdn
├── chalk@0.5.1 (ansi-styles@1.1.0, escape-string-regexp@1.0.3, supports-color@0.2.0, has-ansi@0.1.0, strip-ansi@0.3.0)
├── bower@1.4.1 (is-root@1.0.0, junk@1.0.1, stringify-object@1.0.1, abbrev@1.0.5, user-home@1.1.1, chmodr@0.1.0, rimraf@2.3.3, archy@1.0.0, opn@1.0.2, bower-logger@0.2.2, bower-endpoint-parser@0.2.2, graceful-fs@3.0.6, lockfile@1.0.0, lru-cache@2.6.2, nopt@3.0.1, retry@0.6.1, tmp@0.0.24, request-progress@0.3.1, q@1.4.0, shell-quote@1.4.3, chalk@1.0.0, bower-json@0.4.0, semver@2.3.2, which@1.1.1, fstream@1.0.6, p-throttler@0.1.1, promptly@0.2.0, mkdirp@0.5.0, tar-fs@1.5.0, glob@4.5.3, fstream-ignore@1.0.2, insight@0.5.3, update-notifier@0.3.2, decompress-zip@0.1.0, request@2.53.0, bower-registry-client@0.3.0, github@0.2.4, cardinal@0.4.4, mout@0.11.0, bower-config@0.6.1, configstore@0.3.2, handlebars@2.0.0, inquirer@0.8.0)
└── google-cdn@0.7.0 (regexp-quote@0.0.0, google-cdn-data@0.1.17, async@0.9.0, debug@1.0.4, semver@2.3.2, cdnjs-cdn-data@0.1.1, bower@1.3.12)

grunt-contrib-imagemin@0.9.4 node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin
├── gulp-rename@1.2.2
├── async@0.9.0
├── chalk@1.0.0 (escape-string-regexp@1.0.3, ansi-styles@2.0.1, supports-color@1.3.1, strip-ansi@2.0.1, has-ansi@1.0.3)
├── pretty-bytes@1.0.4 (get-stdin@4.0.1, meow@3.1.0)
└── imagemin@3.1.0 (get-stdin@3.0.2, optional@0.1.3, vinyl@0.4.6, stream-combiner@0.2.1, meow@2.1.0, through2@0.6.5, concat-stream@1.4.8, vinyl-fs@0.3.13, imagemin-svgo@4.1.2, imagemin-jpegtran@4.1.0, imagemin-optipng@4.2.0, imagemin-pngquant@4.1.0, imagemin-gifsicle@4.1.0)
Running "wiredep:app" (wiredep) task

Running "wiredep:test" (wiredep) task

Done, without errors.


Execution Time (2015-05-12 11:38:31 UTC)
loading tasks    9ms  ▇▇▇ 3%
wiredep:app    275ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 90%
wiredep:test    20ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇ 7%
Total 304ms

? Overwrite package.json? overwrite
    force     package.json
   create     .travis.yml
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency karma@>=0.9 included from karma-phantomjs-launcher will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency 
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency karma@>=0.9 included from karma-jasmine will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency 
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency jasmine-core@* included from karma-jasmine will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency 
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency karma@~0.12.0 included from grunt-karma will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency 
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN engine karma@0.12.31: wanted: {"node":"~0.8 || ~0.10"} (current: {"node":"0.12.2","npm":"2.9.1"})

> fsevents@0.3.6 install /Users/Administrator/Work/UnravelNg/node_modules/karma/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents
> node-gyp rebuild

  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/.node: Finished
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/fse.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/fse.node: Finished

> phantomjs@1.9.16 install /Users/Administrator/Work/UnravelNg/node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher/node_modules/phantomjs
> node install.js

Downloading https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-1.9.8-macosx.zip
Saving to /var/folders/qc/r85mm7pn0wd0v76t5hxcj1_40000gn/T/phantomjs/phantomjs-1.9.8-macosx.zip
Receiving...
  [========================================] 99% 0.0s
Received 9187K total.
Extracting zip contents
Removing /Users/Administrator/Work/UnravelNg/node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom
Copying extracted folder /var/folders/qc/r85mm7pn0wd0v76t5hxcj1_40000gn/T/phantomjs/phantomjs-1.9.8-macosx.zip-extract-1431430843250/phantomjs-1.9.8-macosx -> /Users/Administrator/Work/UnravelNg/node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom
Writing location.js file
Done. Phantomjs binary available at /Users/Administrator/Work/UnravelNg/node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs

> ws@0.4.32 install /Users/Administrator/Work/UnravelNg/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/bufferutil.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/bufferutil.node: Finished
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/validation.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/validation.node: Finished
karma-phantomjs-launcher@0.1.4 node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher
└── phantomjs@1.9.16 (which@1.0.9, progress@1.1.8, kew@0.4.0, adm-zip@0.4.4, request-progress@0.3.1, npmconf@2.1.1, fs-extra@0.16.5, request@2.42.0)

karma@0.12.31 node_modules/karma
├── di@0.0.1
├── graceful-fs@2.0.3
├── rimraf@2.2.8
├── colors@0.6.2
├── mime@1.2.11
├── q@0.9.7
├── minimatch@0.2.14 (sigmund@1.0.0, lru-cache@2.6.2)
├── optimist@0.6.1 (wordwrap@0.0.3, minimist@0.0.10)
├── glob@3.2.11 (inherits@2.0.1, minimatch@0.3.0)
├── source-map@0.1.43 (amdefine@0.1.0)
├── log4js@0.6.24 (async@0.2.10, underscore@1.8.2, semver@4.3.4, readable-stream@1.0.33)
├── lodash@2.4.2
├── http-proxy@0.10.4 (pkginfo@0.3.0, utile@0.2.1)
├── connect@2.26.6 (fresh@0.2.4, cookie@0.1.2, pause@0.0.1, cookie-signature@1.0.5, response-time@2.0.1, vhost@3.0.0, on-headers@1.0.0, basic-auth-connect@1.0.0, media-typer@0.3.0, bytes@1.0.0, parseurl@1.3.0, depd@0.4.5, cookie-parser@1.3.4, qs@2.2.4, connect-timeout@1.3.0, finalhandler@0.2.0, debug@2.0.0, method-override@2.2.0, morgan@1.3.2, serve-favicon@2.1.7, csurf@1.6.6, type-is@1.5.7, serve-static@1.6.5, multiparty@3.3.2, errorhandler@1.2.4, compression@1.1.2, express-session@1.8.2, body-parser@1.8.4, serve-index@1.2.1)
├── useragent@2.0.10 (lru-cache@2.2.4)
├── chokidar@1.0.1 (arrify@1.0.0, is-glob@1.1.3, glob-parent@1.2.0, async-each@0.1.6, is-binary-path@1.0.0, readdirp@1.3.0, anymatch@1.3.0, fsevents@0.3.6)
└── socket.io@0.9.16 (base64id@0.1.0, policyfile@0.0.4, redis@0.7.3, socket.io-client@0.9.16)

grunt-karma@0.10.1 node_modules/grunt-karma
└── lodash@2.4.2

jasmine-core@2.3.3 node_modules/jasmine-core

karma-jasmine@0.3.5 node_modules/karma-jasmine
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run with the `--force` flag. But that will ignore any conflict you might come upon.

Conflicts are useful to make sure yeoman won't overwrite any important lines of your custom code.

If you're using Git (or any similar tool), then risk is smaller as you can always diff the changes before committing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My question though is why a tool that is the first tool that you execute in an empty folder has to overwrite something.

Comment: I just tried the yo --force command but I still have to press enter at the end of the process to confirm that I want yeoman to overwrite package.json

Comment: I can see some calls to `invoke` in your log. If two invoked generator touch the same file, then there'll be conflict. This issue have been fixed for a while with better composability feature in Yeoman, but the generator you're using is probably not up to date.

Still, `yo angular --force` should work...